# Make For Loop and Spacial Computing Faster?

Tags: r, performance, geospatial, large-data

I am playing with a large dataset (~1.5m rows x 21 columns). Which includes a long, lat information of a transaction. I am computing the distance of this transaction from couple of target locations and appending this as new column to main dataset:

```
TargetLocation1<-data.frame(Long=XX.XXX,Lat=XX.XXX, Name="TargetLocation1", Size=ZZZZ)
TargetLocation2<-data.frame(Long=XX.XXX,Lat=XX.XXX, Name="TargetLocation2", Size=YYYY)

## MainData[6:7] are long and lat columns

MainData$DistanceFromTarget1<-distVincentyEllipsoid(MainData[6:7], TargetLocation1[1:2]) 
MainData$DistanceFromTarget2<-distVincentyEllipsoid(MainData[6:7], TargetLocation2[1:2])
```

I am using `geosphere()` package's `distVincentyEllipsoid` function to compute the distances. As you can imaging, distVincentyEllipsoid function is a computing intensive but it is more accurate (compared to other functions of the same package `distHaversine(); distMeeus(); distRhumb(); distVincentySphere()`)

Q1) It takes me about 5-10 mins to compute distances for each target location [I have 16 GB RAM and i7 6600U 2.81Ghz Intel CPU ], and I have multiple target locations. Is there any faster way to do this?

Q2) Then I am creating a new column for a categorical variable to mark each transaction if it belongs to market definition of target locations. A for loop with 2 if statements. Is there any other way to make this computation faster?

```
  MainData$TransactionOrigin<-"Other"

  for (x in 1:nrow(MainData)){
  if (MainData$DistanceFromTarget1[x]<=7000)
  MainData$TransactionOrigin[x]="Target1"
  if (MainData$DistanceFromTarget2[x]<=4000)
  MainData$TransactionOrigin[x]="Target2"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It' s a fascinating problem.  I have two questions.

(1) Do you have any near-antipodal points? Vincenty's formula converges very slowly for near-antipodal points.

(2) Do you need the extra accuracy? Do you actually use the distances, or do you just use the categoricals? If the latter, you're actually unlikely to have many (or, indeed, any) categorical values which are changed by using the faster algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Q2 
This will run much faster if you lose the loop.

```
    MainData$TransactionOrigin <- "Other"
    MainData$TransactionOrigin[which(MainData$DistanceFromTarget1[x]<=7000)] <- "Target1"
    MainData$TransactionOrigin[which(MainData$DistanceFromTarget2[x]<=4000)] <- "Target2"
```